# du AND find -ls

Tags: solaris, nfs, disk-usage

I have a Solaris 10 server that has mounted a remote filesystem via NFS.  I believe the remote system is a NetApp, but it's not clear.

When I run `df -h <mountpoint>` I get size 12T, used 10T with a capacity at 87%.

When I change to the mountpoint and run `ls -A |xargs du -s` I get about 8 megabytes.  I have come to expect du to descend recursively and add up all the file sizes, but it doesn't appear to do it here.

As a hedge, I ran

```
find <mountpoint> -ls | awk '{total=total+$7}END{print total}'
```

the answer is 13006791645.  When divided by 1024^3 (1073741824), I get 
about 12.1 terabytes.

So it would seem that `find -ls` and `df` are more or less in agreement.  Why would du fail so greviously?

PS: the command `ls -A` grabs the hidden snapshot directories also but find finds nothing (except "cycle detected").

Comment: `du -s` gives a total per name given on the command line, unless you use `--total` (GNU du only, I don't have Solaris handy to check what options that version of `du` accepts). So did you add up all the numbers given by `ls -A |xargs du -s` ? Why not just do `du -s $mountpoint`?

Comment: It is most unlikely that people use `gdu` on Solaris. In special as it is too dumb to understand extended attribute files.

Comment: 1024^3 byte is a gibibyte, not a terabyte. The 7th field in `-ls` is the file size, not its disk usage

Comment: Related: [Why are there so many different ways to measure disk usage?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/120312)

Answer (score 0):

`du -s` reports in 512-byte blocks. Your comparison with `df -h` can not be made since `du` does not report human readable data.

To compare both values, use either `du -sh <mountpoint>` or `/usr/xpg4/bin/df -P` to let `df` also report in 512-byte units.

According to `man du`:

> Files with multiple links will be counted  and  written  for  only 
>   one entry.  The  directory entry that is selected in the report is
>   unspeci- fied. By default, file sizes are written in 512-byte units,
>   rounded  up to the next 512-byte unit.

Try `/usr/xpg4/bin/df -P` to get 512-bytes reported by `df`:

```
bash-3.2$ /usr/xpg4/bin/df -P /var
Filesystem            512-blocks        Used   Available Capacity  Mounted on
rpool/ROOT/s10/var
                      1147797504    66061270   954397119     7%    /var
```

And compare with `du -s`:

```
bash-3.2$ du -s /var
65976060        /var
```

Or compare:

```
bash-3.2$ df -h /var              
Filesystem             size   used  avail capacity  Mounted on
rpool/ROOT/s10x_u11wos_24a/var
                       547G    32G   455G     7%    /var
```

with:

```
bash-3.2$ du -hs /var   
  31G   /var
```